# Cordova development with JBoss Palette issue

Tags: jquery, eclipse, cordova, jquery-mobile, jboss

I try to learn to develop hybrid applications using JBoss in eclipse.

I have created a hybrid project and I make changes to the `index.html` file.

JBoss provides the developer with the tab Pallete which have availiable `JQuery, Ionic and HTML5` easy to use solutions like forms tables etc.

I have the pallete tab but now I can't see the easy to use solutions. What can I do in order to see the content of pallete tab?

I should see something like that but I only see the pallete tab which nothing
[image]

Any help? What I see actually now is this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to 
1- open the index.html
2- choose the Web Development
Hope that can help!

Sorry I can't attach the screen copy.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, it's ok if you can't attach a screenshot, but if that's the case can you be a little more specific about Step 2?

Answer (score 0):

The step 2 is :
1- generate a cordova project
/ 2- generate a Thym project (eclipse)
 / 3- Inside the Thym project, link it to the cordova project (let take a look here at : **3- Use existing mobile web site** code on **https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/november/article3.php)**